# Why array does not filled with values while For loop, in which each array element[i] is assign with variable?

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

Code compiles ok. I tried to use a debugger but couldn't figure out the problem.
Each iteration "c" is being filled, but it seems like the way I try to assign this variable "c", into the array nothing happens, so that the end print statement ends up "ciphertext: EMPTY NOTHING"

Any help or ideas very welcomed. I'm taking courses and trying to solve a problem set. I'm only begginer, pls do not judje hard :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{

    if(argc < 2 || argc<2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key \n");
        return 1;
    }
    
   
    else if(argc == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
        {
            if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key \n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }



    int key = atoi(argv[1]);


    string initial_text = get_string("plaintext: ");

    
    int cipher[strlen(initial_text)];
    int i = 0;
    int n = strlen(initial_text);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int c = 0;

        if (isupper(initial_text[i]))
        {
            c = (((int)initial_text[i] - 65 + key) % 26) + 65;
            cipher[i] += c;
        }

        else if (islower(initial_text[i]))
        {
            c = (((int)initial_text[i] - 97 + key) % 26) + 97;
            cipher[i] += c;
        }

        
        else
        {
            c=initial_text[i];
            cipher[i] += c;
        }
    }

    //////////////////
    printf("ciphertext: %c\n", (char)cipher);

}
```

Comment: You never initialized the contents of `cipher`. So you're adding `c` to an uninitialized value.

Comment: I think you want `cipher[i] = c;`

Comment: You also didn't allocate enough space for the trailing null byte of `cipher`, and you didn't add the terminator after the loop.

Comment: You define `cipher` as `int`. You probably want `char` as in `char cipher[strlen(initial_text) + 1];`. And, with that, you want: `printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);`

Comment: Also, you probably want: `if(argc < 2 || argc<2 )` --> `if (argc != 2)`. And, because _that_ `if` does `return`, you can remove the `else if (argc == 2) {` and corresponding `}`

Comment: Thank you all, now I have a clue on mistakes. So far everything except variable types were seem to be right, well turned to be wrong. Will try to change the code based on ur comments later. I really appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

1. Using `int` for `cipher` when you [probably] want `char`.
2. Not defining enough space in `cipher` for the trailing 0x00 [EOS] string terminator
3. Not *setting* the EOS at the end.
4. Using `%c` instead of `%s` in your `printf`.
5. `if ((argc < 2) || (argc < 2))` is wrong and can be replaced with `if (argc != 2)`.
6. Because that `if` does `return`, the subsequent `else if` check is no longer needed.
7. "hardwiring" *decimal* values (e.g. `65` for `'A'`).
8. Using `strlen` in the condition expression in a `for` loop. This increases the running time of the loop from O(n) to O(n^2).
9. This can be replaced with (e.g.) comparing the array element against 0x00.
10. Using `strtol` instead of `atoi` and checking the end can do decode *and* validation in a single operation.
11. Don't use `string` when defining `argv` -- use `char **argv`.
12. Your `main` lacks a `return 0;` at the end.
13. There's a lot of replicated code that can be simplified.

Here's the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// I don't have cs50 handy, so a quick hack ...
#define string  char *
string
get_string(const char *prompt)
{
    char buf[1000];
    char *cp;

    printf("%s",prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    do {
        cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

        // IIRC, [real] get_string does heap allocation (vs. static buffer) but
        // for demo purposes here, doesn't really matter
        cp = strdup(buf);
    } while (0);

    return cp;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // check if there is exactly 2 arguments passing, otherwise prompt for a
    // valid key(+return 1, to signal mistake)
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key \n");
        return 1;
    }

    // otherwise check if the key is only a digit and prompt for a valid
    // key(+return 1, to signal mistake)
    // loop through each character in the second argument and validate
    char *arg = argv[1];

    // convert a string to int variable to be used in transformation of letters
    int key = strtol(arg,&arg,10);
    if (*arg != 0) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key \n");
        return 1;
    }

    // prompt for plaintext
    string initial_text = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // create an array of int to store encrypted letters to then be converted
    // in print by (char)
    // NOTE: we need one extra to make room for the trailing EOS
    char cipher[strlen(initial_text) + 1];

    const char *src = initial_text;
    char *dst = cipher;

    for (int chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++, ++dst) {
        if (isupper((unsigned char) chr)) {
            *dst = (((chr - 'A') + key) % 26) + 'A';
            continue;
        }

        if (islower((unsigned char) chr)) {
            *dst = (((chr - 'a') + key) % 26) + 'a';
            continue;
        }

        // for all none alphabetic symbols leave them as they are
        *dst = chr;
    }

    // set the trailing EOS
    *dst = 0;

    // ////////////////
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Very clear!! I will try your improvements tomorrow, and mention if I'd have any problems. Hopefully not)

Comment: thank you, your code works just fine! I'm sorry if the question is dumb, but I don't quite follow how to use pointers. I know it's something to be accessed in memory but still. Could you Please, explain in this case how you used pointers, or add additional comments in ur code to explain the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could write for example

```
if ( argc < 2 || argc<2 || argc < 2 )
```

instead of

```
if ( argc < 2 || argc<2 )
```

and this will be correct but does not make a sense.

Just write

```
if ( argc != 2 )
{
    puts( "Usage: ./caesar key" );
    return 1;
}
```

This else statement

```
else if(argc == 2)
```

is redundant. Remove it.

Instead of this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
{
    if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key \n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

it is simpler to write

```
char *p;
unsigned long ley = strtoul( argv[1], &p, 10 );

if ( *p || key == ULLONG_MAX )
{
    puts( "Usage: ./caesar key" );
    return 1;   
}
```

There is no need to define a variable length array. You could change the original string pointed to by the pointer `initial_text`.

Introducing the variable n is redundant

```
int n = strlen(initial_text);
```

Instead of the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

you could use this loop

```
for ( size_t i = 0; initial_text[i] != '\0'; i++ )
```

Instead of these if statements

```
if (isupper(initial_text[i]))
```

and

```
else if (islower(initial_text[i]))
```

it will be more safer to write

```
if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )initial_text[i]))
```

and

```
else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )initial_text[i] ) )
```

Also using magic numbers like 65 makes the code unreadable. For example you could
write

c = ( initial_text[i] - 'A' + key ) % ( 'Z' - 'A' + 1 ) + 'A';

and

```
c = ( initial_text[i] - 'a' + key ) % ( 'z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a';
```

and instead of the compound assignment operator

```
cipher[i] += c;
```

you need to write

```
initial_text[i] = c;
```

Also in the call of printf you are using incorrect conversion specifier %c and casting

```
printf( "ciphertext: %c\n", (char)cipher);
```

As the string should be updated in place then the call of printf will look like

```
printf( "ciphertext: %s\n", initial_text );
```

Comment: A
Thank you a lot! Have no time rn to make changes, but definitely will tomorrow)